# How do I restore default values for a custom type in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Can't figure out how do I restore default values for my property.
I have a simple form with some TextBoxes that are bond to a property of custom type.
And a button that use command to push collected data into database.
Problem is that I can't restore default values after I click on button and set data into database.

Here is my xaml

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ProdusulCreat.Denumire}"/>

<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Calorii" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProdusulCreat.Calorii}"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="Proteine" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding ProdusulCreat.Proteine}"/>

<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Sare" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProdusulCreat.Sare}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="Zahar" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding ProdusulCreat.Zahar}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Fibre" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProdusulCreat.Fibre}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Text="Grasimi" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding ProdusulCreat.Grasimi}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

<TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Colesterol" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProdusulCreat.Colesterol}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Text="Carbohidrati" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3"  Text="{Binding ProdusulCreat.Carbohidrati}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

<Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Adauga produsul" Command="{Binding AdaugaProdusulCommand}"/>
```

View model

```
#region Properties

#region ProdusModel : ProdusModel - Ingredientul creat
private ProdusModel _ProdusModel = new ProdusModel();

public ProdusModel ProdusulCreat
{
    get => _ProdusModel;
    set => Set(ref _ProdusModel, value);
}
#endregion

#endregion

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

#region Commands
public ICommand AdaugaProdusulCommand { get; }
private bool CanAdaugaProdusulExecute(object ob) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProdusulCreat.Denumire);
private void OnAdaugaProdusulExecuted(object ob) => DataBase.AdaugaProdus(ProdusulCreat);
#endregion
public CreatorIngredienteViewModel()
{
    AdaugaProdusulCommand = new RelayCommand(OnAdaugaProdusulExecuted, CanAdaugaProdusulExecute);
}
```

And a part of Model

```
public class ProdusModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int IDSubCategorie { get; set; }
    public string Denumire { get; set; }
    public string UM { get; set; }
    public string Compozitie { get; set; }
    public double Sare { get; set; }
    public double Zahar { get; set; }
    public double Fibre { get; set; }
    public double Grasimi { get; set; }
    public double Proteine { get; set; }
    public double Colesterol { get; set; }
    public double Carbohidrati { get; set; }
    public double Calorii { get; set; }
    public int Prioritate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: @user1672994 actually I suspect OP is doing that already with the `Set(ref _ProdusModel, value);`

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is impremended in     protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string ProperyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(ProperyName);
            return true;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new model after saving current instance:

```
private void OnAdaugaProdusulExecuted(object ob)
{
    DataBase.AdaugaProdus(ProdusulCreat);
    ProdusulCreat = new ProdusModel();
}
```

all properties will be initialized with default values. since ProdusulCreat property implements notifications, the view will be updated and show those default values

Comment: For fist  time, they are . I want after I imput some values and I "Click" on button to send data to database so set property again to defaul values so I can input another values without deleting old ones from textboxes

Comment: I don't understand what "set property again to defaul values without deleting old ones" means. property cannot have two values simultaneously

Comment: Textboxes are bond to property. So defaul for int is 0 , for string is "", ect. When when I click on tab I load this form with defaul values for all textboxes. 0 for int , ect. I write some data in textboxes so values in property are changed. After i click on button all colected the recordand I  write into database(DataBase.AdaugaProdus(ProdusulCreat);). Next one I want to create another record. But values in textboxes are from old record what i dont need anymore. I want somehow to set values into texboxes to defaul, int 0 , string "" ect.

Comment: your suggestion works fine, But when these types will be collected by the garbage collector? If I create 100 records, I get 100 new objects in memory?

Comment: @Wep4ik, new instance will have default int 0 , string "". old record will not be displayed. it still in memory but not referenced from anywhere so GC will clear it eventually. before that moment there can be 100 objects in memory but GC will get involved if they take too much memory